# This code Doesn't swipe down in Real device But work in emulator (Use Appium)

Tags: android, appium

I am using Appium For Automation this code using for swiping down but when I use it on the real device then it doesn't work. how to solve this for real devices.

```
    Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int start_x = (int) (dimension.width * 0.5);
    int start_y = (int) (dimension.height * 0.8);

    int end_x = (int) (dimension.width * 0.5);
    int end_y = (int) (dimension.height * 0.2);
    
    new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(start_x, start_y))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
    .moveTo(PointOption.point(end_x, end_y)).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a reliable solution, you need to avoid using swipping based on screen dimensions, it is not 100% accurate even if you know the size.

Using AndroidUIAutomator locator you can scroll view up/down automatically right next to the search element, e.g. you know only text "Here it is":

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"Here it is\"))";
```

Personally, I strongly suggest not use text, but check `resourceId` and `className` in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiSelector). Appium docs also has [examples](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/uiautomator-uiselector/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but it's the right way to swiping and need to .5 sec wait to work. UI Automator do not work everywhere.